# git repository phpbb install folder/file

Tags: git, phpbb3

I have cloned the `phpBB` forum because I am working on some styles. Now, I wonder what I should do with the install folder. It is necessary to remove or to rename it to use the forum. But it is part of the cloned repository.

So when I remove it, git will remove it in my repo too and when someone else is cloning from my repo, he won't be able to use the installation.

I could put it on git ignore list, but I fear that would be problematic when I pull updates from upstream.

Comment: Is this just because you are trying to serve the repository directly for testing? Why not "deploy" to a separate folder for testing (which I would think would not have the install folder...).

Answer (score 0):

You can tell Git to stop checking out that folder by using the "sparse checkout" feature. In your clone, create the file `.git/info/sparse-checkout` and insert the following (assuming the install folder is called `install` and lives at the top level of the repo):

```
*
!/install
```

Then enable sparse checkouts:

```
git config core.sparseCheckout true
```

Finally, to update your working tree to match (be careful, this obliterates all uncommitted changes):

```
git reset --hard
```

After that the folder should be gone, or at least you'll be able to delete it and Git won't care anymore.

Comment: @Asara I don't think there is. The ignore list only helps with untracked files (and the install folder is not untracked), and if you delete the folder and simply never commit the deletion, you'll still run into issues on each merge. Setting up sparse checkout once is a lot less hassle than anything else.